# Create temp table in cakephp select

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Anyone knows how to create a model for this kind of query in cakephp?

> select * from (select a,b,c from table1 where a = 'something') as
>   table_alias group by b;

Wherein the inner table is a temp table where i can still pass some conditional arrays (instead of using the ->query() function).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you're using MySQL, the create a VIEW for the temp table. You can then try using that VIEW with the model.

Answer (score 2):

It's documented in the manual including examples. You need to use [buildStatement()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-DboSource.html#_buildStatement) and [expression()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-DboSource.html#_expression).

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries